# Creating a column with moving sum

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a time series data and a non-continuous data logs with timestamps. I want to merge the latter with the time series data, and create a new columns with column values.

Let the time series data be:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(freq=f'{5}T',start='2020-10-10',periods=(12)*24*5))
df['col'] = np.random.random_integers(1, 100, size= df.shape[0])
df['uid'] = 1
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(freq=f'{5}T',start='2020-10-10',periods=(12)*24*5))
df2['col'] = np.random.random_integers(1, 50, size= df2.shape[0])
df2['uid'] = 2
df3=pd.concat([df, df2]).reset_index()
df3= df3.rename(columns={'index': 'timestamp'})

    timestamp             col   uid
0   2020-10-10 00:00:00   96     1
1   2020-10-10 00:05:00   47     1
2   2020-10-10 00:10:00   78     1
3   2020-10-10 00:15:00   27     1    
...
```

Let the log data be:

```
import datetime as dt
 df_log=pd.DataFrame(np.array([[100, 1, 3], [40, 2, 6], [50, 1, 5], [60, 2, 9], [20, 1, 2], [30, 2, 5]]),
                   columns=['duration', 'uid', 'factor'])

df_log['timestamp'] = pd.Series([dt.datetime(2020,10,10, 15,21), dt.datetime(2020,10,10, 16,27),
                dt.datetime(2020,10,11, 21,25), dt.datetime(2020,10,11, 10,12),
                dt.datetime(2020,10,13, 20,56), dt.datetime(2020,10,13, 13,15)])

    duration   uid  factor  timestamp
0    100        1     3     2020-10-10 15:21:00
1    40         2     6     2020-10-10 16:27:00
...
```

I want to merge these two (df_merged), and create new column in the time series data as such (respective to the uid):

```
df_merged['new'] = df_merged['duration] * df_merged['factor']
```

and ffill the df_merged['new'] with this value until the next log for each uid, then do the same operation on the next log and sum, and have it be a moving 2-day average.

Can anybody show me a direction for this problem?

Expected Output:

```
    timestamp             col   uid  duration  factor  new
0   2020-10-10 15:20:00   96     1     100      3      300
1   2020-10-10 15:25:00   47     1     100      3      300
2   2020-10-10 15:30:00   78     1     100      3      300
...
    2020-10-11 21:25:00   ..     1     60       9     540+300 
    2020-10-11 21:30:00   ..     1     60       9     540+300
... 
    2020-10-13 20:55:00   ..     1     20       2     40+540
    2020-10-13 21:00:00   ..     1     20       2     40+540
    ..
    2020-10-13 21:25:00   ..     1     20       2      40
```

Comment: can you share expected output also ?

Answer (score 1):

as I understand it, it's simpler to calculate the `new` column on `df_log` before merging. You'd just use `rolling` to calculate the window for each `uid` group:

```
df_log["new"] = df_log["duration"] * df_log["factor"]
# 2 day rolling window summing `new`
df_log = df_log.groupby("uid").rolling("2d", on="timestamp")["new"].sum().to_frame()
```

Then merging is straightforward:

```
# prepare for merge
df_log = df_log.sort_values(by="timestamp")
df3 = df3.sort_values(by="timestamp")

df_merged = (
    pd.merge_asof(df3, df_log, on="timestamp", by=["uid"])
    .dropna()
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

This solution does deviate slightly from your expected output. The first included row from the continuous series (`df3`) would be at timestamp `2020-10-10 15:25:00` instead of `2020-10-10 15:20:00` since the merge method would look for the last timestamp in `df_log` before the timestamp in `df3`.

Alternatively, if you require the first row in the output to have timestamp `2020-10-10 15:20:00`, you can use `direction="forward"` in `pd.merge_asof`. That would make each row match the first row in `df_log` with a timestamp after the one in `df3`, so you'd need to remove the extra rows in the beginning for each `uid`.